# pyinstaller Error during converting py to exe error : Module 'pythoncom' isn't in frozen sys.path

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have created Tkinter Python Application. but during converting py to exc getting below error. Please help me with this issue.

```
(awwrREPORT) C:\Users\sandip.sable\Desktop\Python\AwwrReport\dist>awwr.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sandip.sable\Anaconda3\envs\AwwrReport\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py", line 40, in <module>
    import win32com  # noqa: E402
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "win32com\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "pythoncom.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "pywintypes.py", line 44, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
ImportError: Module 'pythoncom' isn't in frozen sys.path ['C:\\Users\\SANDIP~1.SAB\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI63642\\base_library.zip', 'C:\\Users\\SANDIP~1.SAB\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI63642\\lib-dynload', 'C:\\Users\\SANDIP~1.SAB\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI63642']
```